# Data is not showing in email from Synchronize DE via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, email-template, sfmcadmin

I have prepared an personalized  email with AMPScript block in the email and now my some of my data attribute  is not showing in the email. I am trying to get this data via lookup function of the AMPScript. While preview and test, the AMPScript block in not showing any error but not displaying the data from synchronized DE.
I want to have AppointmentDate data to be displayed in the email but it's not showing.

Below is my code for the same:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @Contactid = attributevalue("ContactId")
SET @Phone = "1-516-243-3971"
SET @CTA_URL = 'https://google.com/'
SET @Name = [First Name]
SET @Serv_Address = [Service Address: Address]
SET @Comfort_Advisor = [Opportunity Owner: Full Name]
SET @Appt_Date = lookup("ENT.Opportunity_Salesforce_1","Appointment_Date__c","Contactid",@Contact_id)
SET @NewAppt_Date = FormatDate(@Appt_Date,"l","s","")
     
IF NOT EMPTY (@Name) THEN
   SET @Greeting = Propercase(@Name)
   SET @Greeting = "Homeowner"
ENDIF
     
IF NOT EMPTY (@Serv_Address) THEN
   SET @Address = @Serv_Address
    SET @Address = "your home"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Now, I want to show @NewAppt_Date in the email but it's not showing anything.

Please help me with this!

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Is there more ampscript in your email than what you have pasted above? There are no lines above, which might be printing any of the ampscript variables. Did you try printing  @Appt_Date instead? Dows this work?

Comment: Can you confirm if its typo `@Contact_id` should be `@Contactid`

Comment: @LukasLunow this is the ampscript, I am using to fetch the Appt_Date from Opportunity object and then I am using these variables between html to show these personalized email based on the data from DE and synchronize DE.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV Let me check on that